# why Matrix Factorization map the two spaces into same space?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, latent-variable, matrix-decomposition

It's a common sense that *Matrix Factorization* map the two space(e.g. user and item) into **same** factor space. But is there any more formal way to explain the fact they are the **same** ?

Say, I have $$\mathbf {X=AB}$$
where $\mathbf X$ is a user x item matrix.

Then
the $\mathbf B$ map the user space $\mathbf X$ to a low rank user space $\mathbf A$. 
$$\mathbf {XB^{-1}=A}$$
the $\mathbf A$ map the item space $\mathbf X^T$ to a low rank item space $\mathbf B^T$.
$$\mathbf {X^TA^{-T}=B^T}$$

Other than the same number of dimensions, how could I say that the column space of $\mathbf A$  and column space of $\mathbf B^T$ are in same space.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of a formal explanation, but an intuition might come from the recommender system setting you're working in. Suppose we want to predict the rating user $u$ will give to item $i$. This is will be given by

$r_{u,i} = \vec{a}_{u} \cdot \vec{b}_{i}$

Roughly speaking (ignoring the magnitude of the vectors) the predicted rating will be high when the entries of the user and item vectors match up, and low when the entries of the vectors are dissimilar. This leads to the notion that the indices of the vector space correspond to some latent properties of the users and items. For example if we're talking about movies, index 0 for items could somehow capture the notion of "romance", and index 0 for users might in turn represent how much a user likes movies with "romance". Of course its pretty hard to know what the indices really represent, but hopefully they're capturing some properties that explain people's movie watching preferences.